# Arquillian failing a test from and @Observes method

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian

I use an extension to seed db from yml files:

```
package com.acme.data.loader;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.spi.RemoteLoadableExtension;

public class DataSetLoaderExtension implements RemoteLoadableExtension {

    @Override
    public void register(ExtensionBuilder builder) {
        builder.observer(DataSetLoaderObserver.class);
    }

}
```

And the observer class has a method like this:

```
public void beforeClass(@Observes BeforeClass beforeClass) throws Exception {
 ... some code throwing exception ... 
}
```

So when exception is thrown inside that method arquillian is silently swallowing all exceptions. I would like that the test actually fail on any exception happened inside the observer.

Comment: Which version of arquillian are you using? Please try 1.1.5.Final or better version built from master branch and let me know if the problem still persists.

Comment: Great 1.1.5 works as needed, thanks! I was on 1.1.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1.1.5.Final version fixed this issue.